# Automatically check related checkboxes when group checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a list of groups and list of persons as follows:

```
Groups

#  | Group Name
---------------
[] | Grp 1
[] | Grp 2
[] | Grp 3
```

---

```
Persons

#  | Name
-----------
[] | Name 1
[] | Name 2
[] | Name 3
[] | Name 4
[] | Name 5
[] | Name 6
```

Now groups contains some number of persons that are listed in Persons. What I want is when user clicks on some groups, persons belonging to that group should also be get clicked automatically if they are not clicked yet. How can I do this in js?

Both lists are coming from database as a result of ajax request.

---

**Edit**

The html which is generate as response from servlet looks like this:

```
<h4>Groups</h4> 
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="group 1" name="group 1" value="person1,person2,person3" /> Gorup 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="group 2" name="group 2" value="person4,person5" /> Gorup 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="group 3" name="group 3" value="person2" /> Gorup 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="group 2" name="group 2" value="person1,person5" /> Gorup 4
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h4>Persons</h4>    
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="person1" name="person1" value="person1" /> person1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="person2" name="person2" value="person2" /> person2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="person3" name="person3" value="person3" /> person3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="person4" name="person4" value="person4" /> person4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="person5" name="person5" value="person5" /> person5
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="person6" name="person6" value="person6" /> person6
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="person7" name="person7" value="person7" /> person7
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can call this a sample html which I have and have to manipulate.

Comment: Which property shows the connection between persons and groups? Or in other words, how can you see that some person belongs to a group and vice versa?

Comment: -1 for title. Write a more informative title next time please. Now, what are those? `<table>`s? arrays? what? Be more specific please.

Comment: @reporter: The check box with group name have comma separated list of persons.

Comment: @Rikudo: Yes this is `<table>` and `[]` is for check box.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Figure out how to store your relationship between `Groups` and `Persons` in JavaScript.  Something like this should be adequate:

```
groups = {
    group1: ["name1", "name2"],
    group2: ["name3", "name5"],
    group3: ["name4", "name6"]
};
```

In this example, the `{1, 2, 3}` suffixed onto "group" are group-id's, which presumably you should have since your server is sending you the list of groups and it almost certainly is pulling them out of a database where they are uniquely identified by a numeric id.  Same deal for the `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` suffixed onto "name".  These provide your mechanism for locating the things you need within the page.

Step 2 - Come up with a template for displaying your data that provides enough hooks for you to work with.  For instance, something like:

```
<div class="group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="group${group.id}" onclick="toggleGroups(this);" />Group 1
</div>
```

...and:

```
<div class="name">
    <input type="checkbox" id="name${name.id}" />Name 1
</div>
```

Step 3 - Implement your JavaScript handler function for your group checkboxes.  Something like:

```
function toggleGroups(checkBox) {
    var members = groups[checkBox.id];
    for (var index = 0; index < members.length; index++) {
        var memberId = members[index];
        document.getElementById(memberId).checked = checkBox.checked;
    }
}
```

And you're done.  The end result is something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/8wBg7/

Optionally, you may want to consider Step 4 - Making the relationship bi-directional and ensuring that it is always enforced (i.e. keeping your interface sane).  It takes a fair bit of code, but it makes things a whole lot nicer, too.

Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/8wBg7/7/

**Edit** -   And here's one that works with your exact sample markup, minus some obvious typos (and also includes keypress handlers and *does not* depend upon jQuery):  http://jsfiddle.net/8wBg7/8

Comment: There is a problem. My 2 groups can contain some same user.

Comment: @mark - That's not a problem at all.  This approach will correctly handle overlap between groups.  See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/8wBg7/3/

Comment: Try this case: (Step-1.) click on group1. [Name 1,2,3 will be get selected] (Step-2.) click on group2.[Name 5 will be get selected] (Step-3.)Again click on group1/ [Name 1,2,3 will be get unchecked.]. Now here Name 3 should be remain checked as Group2 contains it and group2 is selected. ***This is the problem.***

Comment: @mark - I see, so you want the other selected groups to take priority when toggling a group. Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/8wBg7/7/

Comment: see my edit in question. That is what I get from servlet as response.

Comment: @mark - It should be fairly trivial to update the servlet to produce a data structure and page layout that works with this code.  Failing that, here is a version that works with your exact output (albeit with all instances of "pernson" replaced with "person"):  http://jsfiddle.net/8wBg7/8/

Answer (score 0):

I made an example that shows the functionality you want using Jquery, although I used different subject matter other than people and groups.  Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ftdaP/

Javascript:

```
$("#fruit").click(function(){
    $("input").prop("checked",false);
    $(".fruit").prop("checked", true);
});

$("#veggies").click(function(){
    $("input").prop("checked",false);
    $(".veggy").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="fruit">Apple</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="fruit">Pear</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="fruit">Orange</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="veggy">Tomato</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="fruit">Plum</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="veggy">Green Bean</input>

<a href="#" id="veggies">Veggies</a>
<a href="#" id="fruit">Fruit</a>
```

Comment: jQuery should not be used for anything, he asked about how to do so in Javascript, jQuery is a liable solution, but should only be used if the target technology cannot achieve what he wants.

Comment: Well jquery is a JAVASCRIPT framework, so if you want to get technical I am using the target technology to solve the problem.

Comment: jQuery aside, the question deals with mapping from a group to a set of individuals, not from a group to a distinct class of things.  I'm not sure this solution adequately handles cases such as overlap in the event that a single person is a member of multiple groups.  Unless perhaps you give them a class for every group they are in, but that could be complicated to construct programmatically.

Comment: So how do you suggest hooking the inputs? You could check the value of the checkbox against values in an array

Answer (score 0):

**Update for changed question:**

Given the HTML structure specified, activate the checkboxes with [***jQuery***](http://jquery.com/), javascript like this:

```
$("input:checkbox[name^='group']").change ( function () {

    /*--- Because groups might overlap, we must set the checkboxes based on all
        Group CB values.
    */
    $("input:checkbox[name^='person']").attr ('checked', false);  //-- Clear all, to start.

    $("input:checkbox[name^='group']").each ( function () {
        //--- Loop through each group CB.
        var nameList    = $(this).val ();
        var isChecked   = $(this).attr ('checked') || false;
        if (isChecked) {

            //--- Set each name in the group.
            $.each (nameList.split (','), function (J, nameId) {
                $("#" + nameId).attr ('checked', true);
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWaS2/3/)

---

---

Suppose your associations are like so:

```
var associations    = { Grp_1: ['Name_1', 'Name_3', 'Name_5'],
                        Grp_2: ['Name_2', 'Name_4', 'Name_6'],
                        Grp_3: ['Name_3', 'Name_6']
                    };
```

And HTML like so:

```
<ul id="GroupList">Groups:
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="Grp_1" name="cb_Grp">Grp 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="Grp_2" name="cb_Grp">Grp 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="Grp_3" name="cb_Grp">Grp 3</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="PersonList">Persons:
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="Name_1" name="cb_Name">Name 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="Name_2" name="cb_Name">Name 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="Name_3" name="cb_Name">Name 3</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="Name_4" name="cb_Name">Name 4</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="Name_5" name="cb_Name">Name 5</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="Name_6" name="cb_Name">Name 6</label></li>
</ul>
```

Then the [***jQuery***](http://jquery.com/), javascript code would be like this:

```
$("#GroupList input:checkbox").change ( function () {

    /*--- Because groups might overlap, we must set the checkboxes based on all
        Group CB values.
    */
    $("#PersonList input:checkbox").attr ('checked', false);  //-- Clear all, to start.

    $("#GroupList input:checkbox").each ( function () {
        //--- Loop through each group CB.
        var grpName     = $(this).val ();
        var isChecked   = $(this).attr ('checked') || false;
        if (isChecked) {
            var nameList    = associations[grpName];

            //--- Set each name in the group.
            $.each (nameList, function (J, nameVal) {
                $("#PersonList input[value='" + nameVal + "']").attr ('checked', true);
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWaS2/2/)

---

### Important notes:

1. Notice that the HTML is clean and semantic.
2. Notice that clickable, `label` tags make it much more user-friendly.
3. **Beware answers that only fire on click!**  Users can and will want to use the keyboard, etc. on your site.  Plus it's a requirement and/or the law, depending on where you are.
4. The question didn't properly specify the behavior.  Here, the best assumption is made (clicking a group CB, forces all the name CB's to match the group CB, combined state).

Comment: I don't have data like this: `var associations    = { Grp_1: ['Name_1', 'Name_3', 'Name_5'],
                        Grp_2: ['Name_2', 'Name_4', 'Name_6'],
                        Grp_3: ['Name_3', 'Name_6']
                    };
`. I generate the whole view in servlet and then just display whole responseText of ajax request on page.

Comment: Well, you need to **specify** ***how*** you know what names belong in what group.  Since you didn't, we gave you the simplest JS mechanism for doing that.

Comment: see my edit in question. That is what I get from servlet as response.

Comment: While a good practice, it is most certainly *not* legally required to provide an onchange handler that works with the keyboard as well as the mouse.

Comment: @mark: Updated my answer to handle that HTML structure.  Notice that with jQuery, the handling function did not need much change to adapt.